# Navigation bar button not showing - xcode 12, swift 5

Tags: swift5, xcode12, navigationcontroller

Im trying to build a navigation bar - but simple example is not working.
I'm using xcode 12 and swift 5 - here is sample configuration

[image]

Clicking on button new view is showing - but there is not **Root View Controller** button visible - but when I click in place where it should be it's moving back

What Im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need navigation bar for that second viewController too than you'll need to embed it(second VC) in NavigationBar